# Receiving push messages sent through my phone (Android) to my Raspberry Pi via Pushbullet

Tags: python, pi-3b+, remote, communication

I am already using the Pushbullet API via python running on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to send push notifications upon certain events, that I receive on my Android phone. I would like to also send back notifications, via the Pushbullet android app, that will be received on the Raspberry end and processed.

For example, I am currently alerted (via Pushbullet push) when a sensor connected to the Raspberry reaches a certain threshold. I would like to be able to send a push back with the message "Initialize", to which the Raspberry would run a function within the python code already running.

I wasn't able to figure out how to actually receive and process new push messages, and if this is even a correct approach on the subject.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see the Pi's relevance.  This sounds like a question about the pushbullet software package (whatever that is).

Comment: I get where you're coming from. Pushbullet is just a service that offers an easy API for push notifications. I posted because I am open to any other solution that could achieve the end goal I'm looking for, even if it means changing the platform I'm working with.